# How can I render second child component and disappear first child component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to develop a parent component in which child component will be rendered by default, it has check box, upon clicking on that check box it will render another child component and that first child component should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

set a state with the initial value true a when change the check box set it to false and write condition to `state?  <First/>:  <Second/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`<input type="checkbox">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) element to toggle a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean) state value. Then use that state value to determine which child component is rendered. Here's an example which will render `Component A` when `checked` is `false`, and will render `Component B` when `checked` is `true`, using the [conditional (ternary) operator `?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; } label { display: flex; gap: 0.5rem; margin-bottom: 1rem; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.19.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {useState} = React;

function ComponentA () {
  return (<div>Component A</div>);
}

function ComponentB () {
  return (<div>Component B</div>);
}

function App () {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={ev => setChecked(ev.target.checked)}
        />
        <span>Toggle component</span>
      </label>
      {
        checked
          ? <ComponentB />
          : <ComponentA />
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

reactRoot.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

</script>
```